Unity Visual Studio Assembly C# Player Not Found
So recently I uninstalled Visual Studio 2022 and reinstalled it on the same day but after this I am getting this weird issue where Visual Studio shows red squiggles on random methods and variables but there is no problem on Unity's end as my game works totally fine:


CS1061: 'CharacterStatSO' does not contain a definition for 'GetEditorCharacter' and no accessible extention method 'GetEditorCharacter' accepting a first argument of type 'CharacterStatSO' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried clearing temp files, I tried regenerating the project files, I deleted solution file and regenerated it but no luck. I tried to search it online but again no luck. My game is not breaking and building fine it's just that Visual Studio is having problems and showing false errors which is pretty annoying

Can you check you have the corresponding package in the Package Manager? I doubt you don't since uninstalling VS, shouldn't remove it from your manifest but if VS is not working well with unity, the package is the bridge. Other than that, try regenerating the Library folder, cause some of the assemblies VS links to are artifacts in Library, that constantly get regenerated.

Reinstalling Visual Studio may have caused some settings changed compared to before. You can try the following to correct necessary components:

Check your Visual Studio Installer -> Modify -> Individual components, ensure that Unity Development with C#,  .NET Core SDK, Visual Studio Tools for Unity or maybe other components are correctly installed.

Click Visual Studio Installer -> More -> Repair to fix your Visual Studio.

In Unity, enter Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools, confirm that the External Script Editor is set to Visual Studio and click 'Regenerate project files' to regenerate the project files to modify the connection between Unity and Visual Studio.



Is your problem being solved?  Any feedback is expected. @Aditya

I am really sorry for this late reply as I was out of country, the issue I asked question about was actually never a problem, it is actually a feature of Visual Studio, it was giving me red squiggles because I added the method under UNITY_EDITOR directive and was using it in a method that was not under that directive

I also dont know what to do with this question as if I am trying to delete it stackoverflow recommends me not to delete answered questions
